# Regular expression to remove only beginning and end html tags from string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to remove for example `<div><p>` and `</p></div>` from the string below. The regex should be able to remove an arbitrary number of tags from the beginning and end of the string.

```
<div><p>text to <span class="test">test</span> the selection on.
Kibology for <b>all</b><br>. All <i>for</i> Kibology.</p></div>
```

I have been tinkering with rubular.com without success. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a job better suited for an HTML parser than regex.

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/451590)

Comment: I think in this case the knee-jerk "don't parse html with regex" is unwarranted. [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) has a great blog post on the subject; sometimes you don't need a fully-featured XML parsing library for a specific, trivial task. That said, if you want to try an XML parser, check out [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def remove_html_end_tags(html_str)
   html_str.match(/\<(.+)\>(?!\W*\<)(.+)\<\/\1\>/m)[2]
 end
```

I'm not seeing the problem of  **\<(.+)>** consuming multiple opening tags that Alan Moore pointed out below, which is odd because I agree it's incorrect. It should be changed to **\<([^>\<]+)>** or something similar to disambiguate.

```
 def remove_html_end_tags(html_str)
    html_str.match(/\<([^\>\<]+)\>(?!\W*?\<)(.+)\<\/\1\>/m)[2]
 end
```

The idea is that you want to capture everything between the open/close of the first tag encountered that is not followed immediately by another tag, even with spaces between.

Since I wasn't sure how (with positive lookahead) to say give me the first key whose closing angle bracket is followed by at least one word character before the next opening angle bracket, I said

```
\>(?!\W*\<)
```

find the closing angle bracket that does not have all non-word characters before the next open angle bracket.

Once you've identified the key with that attribute, find its closing mate and return the stuff between.

Here's another approach.  Find tags scanning forward and remove the first n.  Would blow up with nested tags of the same type, but I wouldn't take this approach for any real work.

```
def remove_first_n_html_tags(html_str, skip_count=0)
  matches = []
  tags = html_str.scan(/\<([\w\s\_\-\d\"\'\=]+)\>/).flatten  
  tags.each do |tag|
   close_tag = "\/%s" % tag.split(/\s+/).first
   match_str = "<#{tag}>(.+)<#{close_tag}>"
   match = html_str.match(/#{match_str}/m) 
   matches << match if match
 end
 matches[skip_count]
```

end

Comment: Hey @MichealDodge, it would be better if you provided some explanation with your answer.

Comment: @thomasfedb is right; if the OP couldn't come up with this solution himself, you should assume he'll need some help understanding it.  But this one doesn't even work.  `<(.+)>` consumes the first two tags as i they were one (`<div><p>`), and I'm pretty sure the `\W*` in the lookahead was supposed to be `\s*` (zero or more whitespace characters).

Comment: Thanks, I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Still involves some programming:

```
str = '<div><p>text to <span class="test">test</span> the selection on.
Kibology for <b>all</b><br>. All <i>for</i> Kibology.</p></div>'

while (m = /\A<.+?>/.match(str)) && str.end_with?('</' + m[0][1..-1])
  str = str[m[0].size..-(m[0].size + 2)]
end
```

Cthulhu you out there?

Answer (score -1):

`(?:\<div.*?\>\<p.*?\>)|(?:\<\/p\>\<\/div\>)` is the expression you need.  But this doesn't check for every scenario... if you are trying to parse any possible combination of tags, you may want to look at other ways to parse.

Like for example, this expression doesn't allow for any whitespace between the div and p tag.  So if you wanted to allow for that, you would add `\s*` inbetween the `\>\<` sections of the tag like so: `(?:\<div.*?\>\s*\<p.*?\>)|(?:\<\/p\>\s*\<\/div\>)`.

The div tag and the p tag are expected to be lowercase, as the expression is written.  So you may want to figure out a way to check for upper or lower case letters for each, so that Div or dIV would be found too.

Use [gskinner's RegEx tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) for testing and learning Regular Expressions.

So your end ruby code should look something like this:

```
# Ruby sample for showing the use of regular expressions

str = "<div><p>text to <span class=\"test\">test</span> the selection on.
Kibology for <b>all</b><br>. All <i>for</i> Kibology.</p></div>"

puts 'Before Reguar Expression: "', str, '"'

str.gsub!(/(?:\<div.*?\>\s*\<p.*?\>)|(?:\<\/p\>\s*\<\/div\>)/, "")

puts 'After Regular Expression', str

system("pause")
```

EDIT: Replaced `div*?` to `div.*?` and replaced `p*?` to `p.*?` per suggestions in the comments.
EDIT: This answer doesn't allow for any set of tags, just the two listed in the first line of the question.

Comment: `v*` matches any (0 to infinity) number of `v`s, you mean `.*`. No need to escape `<` and `>`. You don't need to group the alternations (you can remove all the groups).

Comment: yeah i'm looking to parse any html tag.

Comment: @phyatt, do you understand what @Qtax is saying?  Yes, the regex `<p*?>` (for example) will match the string `<p>`, but it will also match strings like `<ppppp>` or `<>`.  And it won't match a tag with attributes, like `<p attr="value">`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Yes, I do.  I rushed when I wrote that answer before because I just wanted to point the user at gskinner's tool for developing Regular Expressions.  I'll edit it soon to be more bullet proof.  Also when I wrote the answer I didn't know he was looking for _any_ html tag.  It sounded like he just wanted to find and remove both a <div><p> and a </p></div>.

Comment: @Qtax  You are right about the `*v`... see the edit. What I've read, you do need to escape the `<` and `>` because they can be used for look ahead and look behind matching.  Maybe Ruby doesn't require them to be escaped, but other regex engines might need them to.  I followed what I saw in the info bar on the right side of gskinners tool.  I usually program in C++, so I think I might "escape" things more than necessary in scripting languages.  Thanks for pointing out the bugs in my answer.

Comment: Angle brackets have special meaning only when they're part of a multi-character construct like a lookbehind, an atomic group, or a named capturing group.  You don't have to escape them when they're on their own any more than you have to escape `:` and `!`, which are used in non-capturing groups and negative lookarounds respectively.

Comment: @phyatt, no major regex flavors require you to escape `<` or `>`, afaik. If you escape them where they were supposed to be part of some other construct you'll get a syntex error. Eg `(?<!foo)` is valid, `(?\<!foo)` is not valid.

Comment: Just doing some additional research on some pages that describe usage of RegEx in grep and ruby, Qtax and AlanMoore have both shown that they know what they are doing with RegEx, especially with the `<` `>` stuff; in grep -w can support a `\<`  or a `\>` to mark a word boundary, like vim does http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html .

Answer (score -1):

I am going to go ahead and answer my own question. Below is the programmatic route:

The input string goes into the first loop as an array in order to remove the front tags. The resulting string is looped through in reverse order in order to remove the end tags. The string is then reversed in order to put it in the correct order.

```
def remove_html_end_tags(html_str)

 str_no_start_tag = ''
 str_no_start_and_end_tag = ''

  a = html_str.split("")

     i= 0 
     is_text = false
     while i <= (a.length - 1)
       if (a[i] == '<') && !is_text
         while (a[i] != '>')
           i+= 1
         end 
          i+=1
       else
         is_text = true
          str_no_start_tag << a[i] 
         i+=1
       end
     end

    a = str_no_start_tag.split("")

    i= a.length - 1 
    is_text = false
    while i >= 0
      if (a[i] == '>') && !is_text
        while (a[i] != '<')
           i-= 1
        end 
        i-=1
      else
        is_text = true
        str_no_start_and_end_tag << a[i] 
        i-=1
      end
   end 

  str_no_start_and_end_tag.reverse!

 end
```

Comment: You'd be far better off using a regular expression. Michael above is more on track.